# String con algunos caracteres en asteriscos

Tags: java, string

Necesito ingresar una linea de texto del estilo:

```
pruebaPRUEBA@gmail.com
```

Y que devuelva:

```
p**********A@gmail.com



    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String email;
    int longitud = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    System.out.println("Ingrese su email");
    email = in.nextLine();
    longitud = email.length();
```

Comment: ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: Es algo muy sencillo, como intentaste hacerlo?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Lo que intente hacer fue length del email pero pienso que seria mejor si puedo separar la parte de antes del  `@` y guardar el `@gmail.com` o  `@hotmail.com` como otro String.

Comment: @user10408376 pon tu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya me quedo. Gracias

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Tarea4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String email;
        int longitudPrimeraParte = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        System.out.println("Ingrese su email");
        email = in.nextLine();

        String primeraParte = email.split("@")[0];
        longitudPrimeraParte = primeraParte.length();
        String segundaParte = email.split("@")[1];

        System.out.print(primeraParte.substring(0, 1));
        for (int i = 0; i <= (longitudPrimeraParte - 2); i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print(primeraParte.substring(longitudPrimeraParte - 1, longitudPrimeraParte)
                + "@" + segundaParte.toLowerCase());

    }

}
```